# How to find triples from two different XML in Marklogic Database?

Tags: xml, marklogic, triples, marklogic-9

Can we extract data from two different XML using one TDE to find triples. Like Subject,Predicate from one XML and Object from other XML. For that how to set the context ??

Comment: Interesting question. Can you elaborate more on your use case?

Comment: Still interested in this. Would also help to have some examples of the XML you're intending. Presumably you have some data in the two XML documents to indicate that they're about the same thing. What does that look like?